# AS3: Duplicating a PNG image causes loss of transparency

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, png, transparency, loader

I am using LoaderMax to load an external PNG and display it in many places so I use the following code to duplicate the image:

```
var cd:ContentDisplay = ContentDisplay(loader.getContent("name"));
var b1 = Bitmap(cd.rawContent);
var old = b1.bitmapData;
var bmp = new Bitmap(b1);

container.addChild(bmp);
```

The original image has a 50% on the alpha channel, but when I create the new bitmap from from the same bitmapData object, it does not preserve the alpha channel.

If I try to copy the alpha channel (see the code below; if I understand correctly, the alpha channel is copied from itself, to itself)- the transparency is on the new image , but the code throws an error...

```
bmp.copyChannel(old, new Rectangle(0, 0, old.width, old.height), new Point(), BitmapDataChannel.ALPHA, BitmapDataChannel.ALPHA);
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property copyChannel not found on flash.display.Bitmap and there is no default value.
    at barmask/frame1()
```

How can I duplicate a PNG and maintain the alpha transparency... preferably without the error?

P.s.  Please forgive any obvious mistakes, I am a ActionScript Newb...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your `BitmapData` instance, passing 3 parameters to the constructor: [`new BitmapData(w, h, true)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#BitmapData%28%29), `Boolean` value is transparency
also check the [`transparent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#transparent) property of the source `BitmapData`

Comment: This didnt seem to work.  I created a new BitmapData with the constructor you recommended, and still had to copyPixels from the old to the new.  This still did not retain the alpha channel.

Comment: and what about `transparent` property of the source `BitmapData`?

Comment: Here is an article about using the BitmapData object http://www.developria.com/2010/02/dealing-with-bitmapdata.html . Here is some code that successfully uses draw() to copy alpha BitmapData into a new Bitmap http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2009/12/riadventure-inspiration.html

Answer (score 2):

His answer was very close to complete:

```
new BitmapData(w, h, true, 0);
```

The last property ensuring that flash doesn't include a background in the new image. That should solve your issue. It has to be exactly "0", not 0x000000, either.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap doesn't have a copyChannel method as the error says :)

Instead of this:

```
bmp.copyChannel(...
```

You need to do this:

```
bmp.bitmapData.copyChannel(...
```